# Sign extension on x64 assembly dword

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, masm

I'm currently doing some programming with x64 assembly using MASM in VS2013. I know that when you provide an integer to an assembly procedure (defined as extern "C" in C++) the integer goes into the rcx register. In this case, the integer is 32 bits, the size of a dword. The only thing I'm not sure about is if the compiler performs sign extension when placing the dword into rcx or zero extension (zero'ing the upper 32 bits and losing the sign of the dword). If anyone can confirm what the compiler does in this instance (since I cannot manually use movsxd and preserve the sign myself) it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

32bit integers are passed in the 32bit part of the register (`ecx` etc), meaning the upper half is zeroed. That doesn't matter, the sign is not lost, it's just not uselessly copied to the 32 high bits. If you work only with the 32bit part of the register (which is normal when operating on 32bit data), all is as it should be. Only when upcasting to 64bit do you need a sign extension.

Comment: If I were to perform "add rdx,rcx" where rdx is a qword (int64) would this not cause an issue given that the upper 32 of rcx is now zero'd?

Comment: @user2379150 it would set the flags wrong. Also, why do that? You can just use 32bit operations to work on 32bit data, saves some space too.

Comment: The idea is to add a dword to qword but if I add a dword to a dword instead I could hit the 32bit limit of the dword versus where if i had a qword I would not. "add edx,ecx" would not make use of the upper 32 bits so what happens if edx is pushed over the 32 bits?

Comment: @user2379150 then it overflows, setting the overflow flag. If you want the larger result, you can just sign-extend first. Well you wrote that you couldn't, but that makes no sense - you can extend it where it is necessary, it doesn't have to be extended from the start.

Comment: So assume var1 is int32 and var2 is int64, you're saying it's easier to perform "add edx,ecx" then to do "movsxd rcx,ecx" and then "add rdx,rcx".

Comment: @user2379150 no, also that's confusing because of your use of "then", surely one of them should be "than"?